# Retain data in android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have a fragment and it has 3 tabs. In each tab I make an API call and get some data. I want this data to be retained when I move out of the tab so that when I move in again it doesnot have to make the API call again. The API calls are expensive so I want to maintain the data of each tab one loaded till the app is active. Currently the API calls are made in Asynctasks and the execute method is call in the onCreate function of the fragment tab.

Is there any way to do it. I am building my first app so I am pretty new at it. Just give me some idea to look at.

Answer (score 0):

So not sure if it's confusing wording but I would do the network calls outside of the fragment that you are using for the tab.

Not sure how you long you want to preserve the data. If it's just for the duration of the application you may want to look at having a retained fragment. That could be used to make the calls and store the data. This is a pretty good tutorial on retained fragments. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html Without any code in your question it's hard to give a concrete example.

If you want to store the data longer term, depending on the nature of the data you could look at shared preferences on a sql database.

Answer (score 0):

Use FragmentPagerAdapter, and override onCreate in Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // expensive actvie
}
```

[Fragment life circle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

[FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)